# $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$, $f_n\to g$ in $L^p{'}$ then $f=g$ a.e $x$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

If $f_n \in L^p\cap L^p{'}$ such that $p\neq p'$ and $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$, $f_n\to g$ in $L^p{'}$ then $f=g$ a.e $x$.

a suggestion please.

Comment: $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ implies $f_{n_k} \to f$ a.e. for some subsequence $n_k.$

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the subsequence argument you can use Chebyshev's inequality. For any $t > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ you have $$\mu(\{|f_n - f| > t/2 \}) \le \frac{2^p}{t^p} \|f_n - f\|_p$$ and $$\mu(\{|f_n - g| > t/2 \}) \le \frac{2^{p'}}{t^{p'}} \|f_n - g\|_{p'}$$ so that $$\mu(\{|f - g| > t\}) \le \frac{2^p}{t^p} \|f_n - f\|_p + \frac{2^{p'}}{t^{p'}} \|f_n - g\|_{p'}.$$ Since $n$ is arbitrary you can let $n \to \infty$ to conclude that $\mu(\{|f - g| > t\}) = 0$ for all $t > 0$ so that $f=g$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.